How to (idiomatically) read indexed arrays from a delimited text file?
I have text files from an external source that are formatted like so:
       0       0    -0.105961      0.00000
       1       0     -1.06965      0.00000
       1       1   -0.0187213    -0.240237
       2       0    -0.124695      0.00000
       2       1    -0.178982    0.0633255
       2       2     0.760988    -0.213796
       3       0     -1.96695      0.00000
       3       1    0.0721285    0.0491248
       3       2    -0.560517     0.267733
       3       3    -0.188732    -0.112053
       4       0   -0.0205364      0.00000
       ⋮        ⋮        ⋮              ⋮
      40      30     0.226833    -0.733674
      40      31    0.0444837    -0.249677
      40      32    -0.171559    -0.970601
      40      33    -0.141848    -0.137257
      40      34    -0.247042    -0.902128
      40      35    -0.495114     0.322912
      40      36     0.132215    0.0543294
      40      37     0.125682     0.817945
      40      38     0.181098     0.223309
      40      39     0.702915     0.103991
      40      40      1.11882    -0.488252

where the first two columns are the indices of a 2d array (say i and j), and the 3rd and 4th columns are the values for two 2d arrays (say p[:,:] and q[:,:]). What would be the idiomatic way in Python/Julia to read this into two 2d arrays?
There are some assumptions we can make: the arrays are lower triangular (i.e., the values only exist (or are nonzero) for j <= i), and the indices are increasing, that is, the last line can be expected to have the largest i (and probably j).
The current implementation assumes that maximum i and j is 40, and proceeds like so: (Julia minimal working example):
using OffsetArrays
using DelimitedFiles: readdlm

n = 40

p = zeros(0:n, 0:n)
q = zeros(0:n, 0:n)

open(filename) do infile
    for i = 0:n
        for j = 0:i
            line = readline(infile)
            arr = readdlm(IOBuffer(line))
            p[i,j] = arr[3]
            q[i,j] = arr[4]
        end
    end
end

Note that this example also assumes that the index j changes the fastest, which is usually true, but in doing that it effectively ignores the first two columns of the data.
However, I'm looking for a solution that makes fewer assumptions about the data file (maybe only the lower-triangular one and the index increasing one). What would be a "natural" way of doing this in Julia or Python?

The code in the question is almost there. Here is a Julian way to do this:
using DelimitedFiles, OffsetArrays

rawdata = readdlm("in.txt");
irange = (:)(Int.(extrema(rawdata[:,1]))...)
jrange = (:)(Int.(extrema(rawdata[:,2]))...)

p = OffsetArray(zeros(length.((irange,jrange))),irange,jrange)
q = copy(p)

foreach(eachrow(rawdata)) do (i,j,pd,qd)
    p[Int(i),Int(j)] = pd
    q[Int(i),Int(j)] = qd
end

This isn't the simplest/prettiest code, but data parsing rarely is.
After the foldl, the matrices p and q should hold the correct values (and can be cast to a TriangularMatrix type if desired).
The initial bit with irange and jrange can be even shortened:
rngs = Tuple(splat(:).(extrema(Int.(rawdata[:,1:2]);dims=1)))
p = OffsetArray(zeros(length.(rngs)),rngs...)
q = copy(p)


Something like following (in Python)?
data = []
with open('demo.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        tokens = line.split()
        if len(tokens) == 4:
            i = int(tokens[0])
            j = int(tokens[1])
            p = float(tokens[2])
            q = float(tokens[3])
            data.append((i, j, p, q))

print(data)


I focused on reading any line in file - not your array logic

Try to read from the end of the file, some insights here How to read a file in reverse order?
You may also read the file and load data into a triangle 2-d array as normal, and then expand the other lines according to the last line, like the following
def read_and_return_triangle():
 //some logic and return things like [[0], [0, 1], [0,1,2]]


triangle = read_and_return_triangle()
max_l = len(triangle[-1])

for line in triangle:
  line += [0]* (max_l - len(line))

print(triangle)



